# Adding draggable event to rows inside a table inside bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop, html-table

I am having a hard time figuring this out, I need to drag the rows inside a table. I am using tablednd plugin. Here is my code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="id1" href="#tab1">Page 1<span class="closeIcon"></span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="id1">
<table class="scrollable">
<tr>
<td>one</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>two</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

in my javascript:

```
 $(".scrollable").tableDnD
    ({
        onDragClass : "DraggingClass",

        onDrop: function (table, row) {

            alert();

        }
                });
```

This is not working when I add the rows dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure it out using the following link [Drag and drop not working after adding new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635915/drag-and-drop-not-working-after-adding-new-row)

After adding the row, making use of the follwoing function to add draggable events for new rows.

$("#tableId").tableDnDUpdate()