# Jquery - Function Inside DIV not working after refreshed

Tags: jquery

I have a table "group1" contains table and rows. I use this plugin (tableDnD) to drag the row up/down, and it is all working fine. I have another Jquery function that delete row inside the DIV "group1" and the refresh the DIV only, this also works fine.

```
    $('#group1').tableDnD({
    onDrop: function(table, row) {      
        $.post('updateRecord.asp?', {
            pagesid : "1",
            arr : $.tableDnD.serialize()
        }); 
    }
});
```

Now, after the rows deleted, updated DB, then refreshed the DIV, the jQuery above with option drag row up/down is no longer working (if I refresh entire page, it would work).  I did some research and see people suggested about using delegate option, but I am not sure how to apply to the `$('#group1').tableDnD` function.

Updated - I tried this, but no luck.

```
$(document).on('tableDnD', '#group1', function(){
onDrop: function(table, row) {      
    $.post('updateRecord.asp?', {
        pagesid : "1",
        arr : $.tableDnD.serialize()
    }); 
}
```

});

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own event and call it

```
 $('body').on('apply_tableDnD', '#group1', function() {
  $('#group1').tableDnD({
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
      $.post('updateRecord.asp?', {
        pagesid: "1",
        arr: $.tableDnD.serialize()
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This will call after div has been refreshed

```
$('#group1').trigger('apply_tableDnD');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is not working.  Maybe I am doing something wrong, still playing around...

Comment: have you put `$('#group1').trigger('apply_tableDnD');
` after refresh div? put a debugger and check your console as well for any errors

Comment: Yes, I did. I put it inside my $.ajax... success: and right after the refresh DIV.

Comment: After I moved things around in the Ajax.  Your suggestion works perfect.  Thank you @Curiousdev

Answer (score 0):

Update: It looks like this question has already been asked - [Drag and drop not working after adding new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635915/drag-and-drop-not-working-after-adding-new-row) 
Please look at the answer by **meataxe**.

Take a look at this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

I'm not sure, but you may be able to pass the tableDnD function like this:

```
$(document).on('tableDnD', '#group1', function(){
    // code for on drag
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried that but no luck. (Updated my post)

Comment: The plugin may not support delegation. In that case, I would use some thing like this as a work around: https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/. On mouse down, access by class, verify it's the row you want. Then you can do $(this).tabeDnd(function(){});

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635915/drag-and-drop-not-working-after-adding-new-row

Comment: Thank you @jobenscott.  The link is very helpful and it works.