# slider not working inside tab inside tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im building a web app using the [NativeDroid](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/material/) . Everything seems to be working fine but inside a tab panel, when i add a slider it doesnt work.

But it works when i refresh. But when i click the link through the menu it doesnt work until i refresh it

I have uploaded the pages over here [Demo](http://www.vidznet.com/tabupdated/test2.html) from the menu when u click on profile you will see the slider is not working.. There are no jquery errors on my console too.

below is code that i have used for the slider and a chart

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", ".page_bubble", function () {
 $('.demo').percentcircle({

                animate: true,
                diameter: 100,
                guage: 2,
                coverBg: '#f4f8f9',
                bgColor: '#f4f8f9',
                fillColor: '#5c93c8',
                percentSize: '19px',
                percentWeight: 'normal'

            });
            $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

                navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
                slideSpeed: 300,
                paginationSpeed: 400,
                singleItem: true,
                navigationText: ['']



            });

        });
```

Can someone tell me what might be causing it?

Comment: Firstly you don't need multiple document.ready event handlers; you can join them in to one. Your actual issue is probably because the content doesn't exist when the page loads. You need to initialise the relevant plugins after their HTML has been added to the DOM by your tab control. Exactly how you do that will depend on the tab control you're using, and the events it exposes

Comment: Which tab panel plugin you are using ?

Comment: @Curiousdev im using http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/material/ it already has its own tabs. the documentation is over here http://nativedroid.scripter.click/tabs/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i did wraped the code in `$(document).on("pagecreate"` (i updated my question) but still doesnt seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

```
el.on("click",".nd2Tabs-nav-item:not('.nd2Tabs-active')",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _self.switchTab($(this),$(this).data('tab'),$(".nd2Tabs-nav-item").index($(this)[0]));
});
```

This is the `event` in `nativedroid2.js` where you need to add your `percentcircle` and `owlCarousel` binding event as below as @rory-mccrossan said on page load content doesn't exist that's reason it's not working change you js like below

```
el.on("click",".nd2Tabs-nav-item:not('.nd2Tabs-active')",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _self.switchTab($(this),$(this).data('tab'),$(".nd2Tabs-nav-item").index($(this)[0]));
    $('.demo').percentcircle({

     animate: true,
     diameter: 100,
     guage: 2,
     coverBg: '#f4f8f9',
     bgColor: '#f4f8f9',
     fillColor: '#5c93c8',
     percentSize: '19px',
     percentWeight: 'normal'
   });
   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true, 
      slideSpeed: 300,
      paginationSpeed: 400,
      singleItem: true,
      navigationText: ['']
  });

});
```

Or You can make a delegate event and trigger that event here for more info please find [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43124919/2534646)

Comment: can i wrap it inside a `$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){` and make it work?

Comment: also i did try your method, doesnt seem to be working :(

Comment: Yes you can do that to make it work i have mentioned a link where you can find you have to `trigger()` that method on tab change

Comment: put a debug point and see what happens is it called or not? or any errors in console as well

Comment: I think it doesnt call at all and no errors on the console view.. Also do you think we should trigger it when the link is clicked (it didnt work for me either) coz the slider is on the first tab, so we dont need to click on the tabs. When i refresh the page it seems to be working properly.  So there might be some event that im missing when the link has been clicked

Comment: can you provide any demo link what you have done where i can figure out what actually goes wrong?

Comment: You can check it over here http://www.vidznet.com/tabupdated/test2.html

Comment: It seems like these are just tabs it's working fine than what goes wrong? put a Carousel inside tab as aforementioned and let me know if it'll not work

Comment: on that page when u click on the menu you will see a link to the profile.. Once u click on that you will see the carousal

Comment: `<a href="test1.html" class="ui-link waves-effect waves-button" data-ajax="false">Profile</a>` change your profile anchor link like this and it'll work  just added attribute`data-ajax="false" `:-)

Comment: great.. Its working... :) Is it possible get the carousal working without removing `data-ajax="false"` coz the page is not loading smoothly :)

Comment: I need to analyzed more on that give me some time to understand the internal structure what exactly it's going i'll let u know if it's possible to do the same :-) cheers